# YouTube IFrame Player doesn't execute cuePlayList correctly

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have a website where I create a YouTube player in an IFrame and make it grab different playlists depending on what the user clicks. So it calls `player.cuePlaylist({listType:"playlist",list:playListID})`
where `playListID`is the variable that changes when the user calls for different playlists. The problem is the first time the function gets executed it works fine, but as soon as it's asked a second time to cue a new playList, it doesn't do anything, no 400 error message or anything either, but when I call the second playList a **second** time, it works.

This cuePlayList function seems to be bugged as this did not occur a month or two ago. The only change I can see to the youtube Iframe API is about search lists, not playlists as you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Revision_History)

I recreated the bug in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogruwzdL/1/). Just press the "new playlist" button and it will load the correct playlist, press another playlist and it won't do anything until pressed twice.

So am I doing something wrong or is this on YouTube's IFrame API end?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same issue with both cuePlaylist and loadPlaylist. Thanks for your post, as it's inspired me to give up on trying to read through the Youtube API docs and come up with a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of destroying the player, meaning you can't use `cuePlaylist()` and `loadPlaylist()` anymore, I found out the player accepts the new playlist if you call the cue/load function twice like so: https://jsfiddle.net/5yw2na96/

I found out about this issue by linking the `cuePlaylist()` function to a button and noticing you need to click twice for the playlist to update correctly. There seems to be a delay needed between the empty call and the actual call so I set it to 500ms.

Comment: Yeah it's like I showed in my example, calling the function twice with a delay is a decent workaround for now till it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The method described above, chaining an empty call and the actual cue function after a certain amount of milliseconds, appears to not be working anymore if you also have to specify a specific index to start from. The new playlist is correctly loaded but the index is set back to 0 no matter where in the playlist you were when the update happened.

There's nothing much to change from the method above to fix the issue: you can simply assign a callback function to a variable and chain that instead. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/o0f815t3/

```
const cIndex = player.getPlaylistIndex(),
  cTime = player.getCurrentTime(),
  callback = function() { player.cuePlaylist(myPlaylist, cIndex, cTime) };
callback();
setTimeout(() => { callback() }, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a workaround by destroying the player and initializing a new one with the playlist I'd like to load.

```
    embed.destroy();
    embed = new YT.Player('video-placeholder', {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        playerVars:
            {
                listType: 'playlist',
                list: playlistId,
                index: 0
            },
        events: {
            'onReady': function (event) {
                player = event.target;
            }
        }
    });
```